# How to Automate CAPTCHA in cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am not able to get id/class for automation in cypress.

[image: the form image is attached for more clarification]

Comment: CAPTCHA, by definition, is a system to tell humans and computers apart, so cypress shouldn't be able to get a check from reCaptcha

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of a Captcha is that you *can't* automate it.

Configure your test environment to omit the Captcha requirement instead.

Comment: How I can omit the Captcha? kindly guide me i am new in cypress family

Comment: The code *you are testing* needs to omit the Captcha when it is in a test environment. The specifics have nothing to do with Cypress.